# Why if my EntityData model invalid?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I have created an azure mobile app following the guides provided by Microsoft.

I am trying to update my database to reflect the model but when I run Add-Migration Init I get: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'theactivitynetworkService.DataObjects.Activity'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys.

Can someone explain this error as I can't understand how the docs apply to my instance.

Thanks

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace theactivitynetworkService.DataObjects
{
    public class Activity : EntityData
    {
        public int ActivityId { get; set; }
        public Activity() { }
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserProfile : EntityData
    {
        public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
        public UserProfile()
        {
            Activities = new List<Activity>();
        }
        public string UserProfileBio { get; set; }
        public string UserProfileLastLocation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    }

}
```

EDIT: 
This is the EntityData Class - it shows as 'from metadata'. Any advice appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables;

namespace Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     An abstract implementation of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables.ITableData
    //     interface indicating how the system properties for a given table data model are
    //     to be serialized when communicating with clients when using Entity Framework
    //     for accessing the backend store. The uniform serialization of system properties
    //     ensures that the clients can process the system properties uniformly across platforms.
    //     Concrete entity framework models can derive from this base class in order to
    //     support the system properties.
    public abstract class EntityData : ITableData
    {
        protected EntityData();

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Index(IsClustered = true)]
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
        public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
        public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Okay, so if I remove the `[Key]` annotation and run `add-migration init` it works fine, but `update-database` throws: `Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and constrained to be nonnullable.`

Comment: Maybe your EntityData class already has a key defined?

Comment: Thanks, spotted it - I see its already there. If I remove my own keys then it complains the key is not of type int - how do I change it's type in the example above?

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to be `string` "by design"

Comment: Okay, so if I remove the [Key] annotation and run add-migration init it works fine, but update-database throws: Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and constrained to be nonnullable.

Comment: Your Id (and a few other fields) come from the abstract class so all you need is your own properties. Here is a link on migration issues. https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/mobile-services/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations.md

Comment: Okay, this seems to apply where I have an existing database - what if I a starting a new project?